# SQLite Foreign Key Error

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am just starting to learn JDBC, and here occurred a problem. I have tables Doctor and Patient. They are successfully created with own ids in them, but I can't create following Table:

```
String sqlVisit = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Visit (" +
       "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," +
       "doctor_id INTEGER NOT NULL," +
       "FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES Doctor (id)," +
       "patient_id INTEGER NOT NULL," +
       "FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES Patient (id),"+
       "cost DOUBLE NOT NULL," +
       "date DATE" +
       ")";
```

Error line:

```
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "patient_id": syntax error)
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, tried to find solution but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you post full code? This is not enough for us to help you

Comment: Here is full code: https://pastebin.com/zrfFGeZg

Comment: It worked for me, it's best practise to define keys at the end `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Visit (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  doctor_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  patient_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  cost DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  date DATE,
  FOREIGN KEY (doctor_id) REFERENCES Doctor (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES Patient (id)
);`

Comment: Now it worked! Thank you for your help, I'll keep that in mind for future